# Определение страны пользователя и его редирект на другой под-домен (сервер)

Tags: php, javascript, редирект

Приветствую. Я хотел бы понять как определить страну пользователя (желательно на языке PHP) на своем сайте, и после отправить его на соответствующий раздел или под-домен сайта (или вовсе в другой сервер), это необходимо чтобы к примеру пользователь из Казахстана зашедший на сайт site.ru (который расположен в России и имеет стандартный русский язык) автоматический был перенаправлен на другой под-домен к примеру https://kz.site.ru, который имеет другой интерфейс а также Казахский язык. Спасибо! С уважением, Разработчик!

Comment: берете где-то список ip и по ним определяете.... к примеру http://www.programva.com/ru/ip-adresa-evropa-rosija-mir ..... казахстан: http://www.programva.com/ru/ip-adresa-evropa-rosija-mir/KZ-KAZ-Kazakhstan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я пользуюсь Tabgeo (к сожалению проект умер, однако суть я думаю Вы поймете).

Скачивайте отсюда оба файла 
https://github.com/dostelon/TabGeo/tree/master/src/TabGeo и кладете, например, их в папку tabgeo

Определяем код страны

```
include('tabgeo/country.php');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$lang = country($ip);    
$lang=strtolower($lang);
```

Делаем редирект

```
if ($lang=='kz') {
header("Location: http://kz.site.ru/"); 
}
```

Comment: А крым в этой библиотеке уже наш?

Comment: думаю что нет и врядли будет